# Can't get elasticsearch synonyms to work.. what's wrong?

Tags: elasticsearch, sense

I have set up `ES` on my local pc and installed `Chrome Sense`. I am now trying to get synonyms working in a `multi_match` query, but just not getting anywhere with it. Here is my Sense queries for you to try replicate what I'm seeing...

**Create a test index with some simple synonyms and basic stemming** etc

```
POST /test
{
    "settings" : {
        "analysis" : {
            "filter" : {
                "synonym_expand" : {
                    "type" : "synonym",
                    "expand" : 1,
                    "synonyms" : [
                        "strawberry, apple, banana, grape, fruit",
                        "queen, king, monarch"
                    ]
                },
                "english_stemmer" : {
                    "type" : "stemmer",
                    "language" : "english"
                }
            },
            "analyzer" : {
                "lens-english" : {
                    "type" : "custom",
                    "tokenizer" : "standard",
                    "filter" : [
                        "lowercase",
                        "stop",
                        "english_stemmer",
                        "synonym_expand"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "mappings" : {
        "video" : {
            "properties" : {
                "Description" : {
                    "type" : "string",
                    "index_analyzer" : "lens-english",
                    "search_analyzer": "lens-english"
                },
                "Title" : {
                    "type" : "string",
                    "index_analyzer" : "lens-english",
                    "search_analyzer": "lens-english"
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

**Then post 2 documents to it**

```
POST /test/test
{
    "Title" : "The diet plan",
    "Description" : "Eat a lot of bananas and custard"
}

POST /test/test
{
    "Title" : "The Queens visit",
    "Description" : "this is the day that elizebeth when ape at her subjects for having a strawberry fight"
}
```

**now test if the synonyms have being expanded**

```
GET /test/_settings
```

and I see that they do.

If we now pass a test phrase throught the analyzer, we see that all terms are extracted and therefore should be indexed.

```
POST /test/_analyze?analyzer=lens-english
{Monarch fruit.}
```

And they do... great stuff so far!

Now this is where I do the search for the query containing 'fruit', which is in the synonym list. So I'd expect that the both documents containing the word `Strawberry` and `banana` should match, right?

```
GET /test/test/_search
{
    "query": {
        "multi_match": {
           "query": "fruit",
           "fuzziness":"AUTO",
           "fields": [
              "Title",
              "Description"
           ]
        }
    },
    "highlight": {
        "fields": {
            "Title":{},
            "Description":{}
        }
    }
}
```

and.. nothing, no hits!

I even tried changing the mappings section to use the standard analyzer at search time as follows

```
"mappings" : {
    "video" : {
        "properties" : {
            "Description" : {
                "type" : "string",
                "index_analyzer" : "lens-english",
                "search_analyzer": "standard"
            },
            "Title" : {
                "type" : "string",
                "index_analyzer" : "lens-english",
                "search_analyzer": "standard"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but nothing, nada!

> Anyone with Elasticsearch knowledge on here that can spot what's going on?

Comment: Ahh DOH!I got it working. I misspelled the mapping name ... I got 'video' in there when it shoulda been 'test' (the document name)